# Container network exposing only one container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file, which refers to two images to build the container and the default network.

Those images are a react web app and a Dotnet core web API. When I run the docker-compose file, as you know, it creates two containers with the default network.

When the docker-compose file is deployed, I can access both containers, I can see the react web app, and use the browser or postman to do a call to the API. Of course, the react app is able to call the API.

My question is, is there a way to avoid the API being "public" from outside the default network? What I want is for only the react app can call the API, not a browser or postman.

Here is the docker-compose file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    front-app:
        image: <image>
        build: <image path>
        ports:
            - "3000:80"
        links:
            - back-app
    back-app:
        image: <image>
        build: <image path>
        ports:
            - "5000:5000" 
            - "5001:5001"
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=https://+:5001
            - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
```

I am new in this world of docker, I think is a pretty simple docker-compose file, but if you see something wrong, please, let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid the API being "public" from outside the default network? What I want is for only the react app can call the API, not a browser or postman.

This isn't possible, Docker or otherwise.  The important part is that the React application runs in the end user's browser, not a container, and when it makes calls to the API service those calls come from outside Docker (and in non-developer environments from a different host).  Those calls *are* coming from a browser, and you can't reliably distinguish your application from other Javascript code from debugging tools like Postman or Curl.

Putting both parts behind a reverse proxy can be a good practice, and can allow the browser application to request path-only URLs like `/api/...` without a host name (avoiding problems both with CORS and with needing to embed a host name in the application code).  If you do that then you can remove the other `ports:` blocks.  Your API still must be publicly accessible via that reverse proxy, though.